# Deep-Linking in Framework using Domain URL in iOS

Tags: ios, frameworks, deep-linking, url-scheme, ios-universal-links

I gonna give support for Deep-Linking in my Framework. I analysed lot of Tutorial, All are detailed about **Universal Linking** and **URL Scheme**.

For **Universal Linking** I need to host **apple-app-site-association** file in associated domain. The **apple-app-site-association** file contain team ID + Bundle ID.  Its not scalable in Framework case.

For **URL Scheme**  we need to redirect to custom URI Scheme.

Apart from this, I looking a solution as like as Android App Links.

Is there any way to do **Deep-linking with Domain URL**, without using **Universal Linking**?

Comment: Deep-linking with Domain URL - if you do like , its automatically redirect to safari correct, if yes inside your URL (backend code) add the condition for redirect to the app,

Comment: Yes I know that @Anbu.karthik, But my need is, For Eg : My domain URL is **[https://www.examble.com](https://www.examble.com)**, if I added **www.examble.com** in my Plist **URL Scheme** it will redirect to the application. Am looking for a Solution Like this.

Comment: in here apps only work on two modes 1. X-auth 2. O- auth , so in here we need call back for e.g  -- > ://, but we do some hacky or tricky method in backend,

Answer (score 2):

**No, you must use Universal Links.** Apple needs you to verify that you actually own that domain and that it is associated with your app. Same with Android app links. Your only option is to try and use URI schemes.